# How to modify the value returned by form submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, form-submit

Currently, I use a form with four select elements to ask the user the selection parameters (for Wordpress posts but this is not a Wordpress problem). Doing so, the normal submit of a form returns something like

some_url/some_partial_url?select1=val1&select2=val2&select3=val3&select4=val4

However, I would like the submitted string to look like this:

some_url/some_partial_url/tag/val1,val2,val3,val4

Up to now, I have managed to create and submit such a string using Javascript but I couldn't find out so far how to get rid of the "?select1=val1&select2=val2&select3=val3&select4=val4" part which is still appended to the returned submit string. Should I set or clear another form variable or is there another way to get rid of this appended part?

Please do not recommend any packages such as jQuery but only 'native' Javascript solutions.

Comment: Just _don’t_ submit the form (which will create the format you don’t want automatically), but assign your created string to `location.href` instead to change to that URL.